# Creating relation for duplicate lines

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, line, relates, duplicates

I have two datasets with some duplicate lines. I can select the duplicates with GRASS `v.select`:

```
v.select ainput=map1 binput=map2 output=duplicates operator=equals
```

or QGIS `Select by Location`:

```
qgis_process run native:extractbylocation --distance_units=meters --area_units=m2 --ellipsoid=EPSG:3827 --INPUT='map1.gpkg' --PREDICATE=3 --INTERSECT='map2.gpkg' --OUTPUT='ogr:dbname='duplicates.gpkg'\'' table="output" (geom)'
```

How do I create a relation between any two matching lines so I may delete the duplicates but retain the unique attributes of the other dataset?

In other words, I need to mark the attributes of one line with the ID of the other duplicate line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Extract the duplicate features to a new (temporary) layer using "Extract by expression" with the expression `overlay_equals(@layer)`

[image: Extract by expression in QGIS]

2. Run "Join attributes by location" using your main layer as base layer and the layer created in step 1 as join layer.

[image]

The resulting attribute table contains the attributes with "_2" (etc.) suffix for the attributes of the joined features.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that should work. I'll give it a shot and of course accept your answer if it works.

Comment: I ended up using `Join attributes by nearest` to compensate for float precision but it did the trick. Not sure how I missed them, but thank you! BTW: funny you used Boise as an example - I live about an hour away.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Was looking for example data. Stumbled upon your GIS SE profile where Idaho is mentioned. :)